# Why do we assume $p_n \neq p$ for each $n$ again in continuity proof?

Tags: real-analysis

When trying to prove equivalence of continuities (sequential, and epsilon-delta), we always demand the convergent sequence to be $p_n \neq p$ (the limit), but I forgot why.

Comment: So what happens with the constant sequence $p$?

Comment: Then we get $f(p_n) = f( p) $ for all $n$

Comment: Yes. The reason is clarified in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you allow constant sequences, the equivalence does not hold: any function (continuous or not) satisfies $f(p)=\lim_nf(p_n)$ when $p_n=p$ for all $n$.

Comment: Why does the equivalence not hold? You just said this will be alway true.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you allow constant sequences, then every function would be sequentially continuous.

Comment: Okay, I got you. Could you provide me a concrete example where if even one term in the sequence is equal to its limit, we would not get equivalence?

Comment: No, of course that doesn't exist. Any time you are talking sequences, you could prescribe whatever you want for the first two million elements, and that would have no bearing in the limit. So yes, if you want to be precise, the assertion should be "$p_n\ne p$ for big enough $n$".

Comment: I suspect this equivalence holds only in $\mathbb{R}.$ I am sure we can define a metric to make my question more enlightening?

Comment: No, the equivalence between sequential and $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ continuity holds in any metric space.